# how to add something in JSON file using python?

Tags: python, json

yeah. (sorry my bad english T_T)

```
{
  "BlockA": {
    "BlockB": {
      "name": "BlockB",
      "value": "Value_B"
    }
}
```

this is just my simple json file.

and, i need to change this for

```
{
  "BlockA": {
    "BlockB": {
      "name": "BlockB",
      "value": "Value_B"
    },
    "BlockC": {
      "name": "BlockC",
      "value": "Value_C"
    }
}
```

like this, i tried append, json.loads, json.load, json.dumps, json.dump..
but all functions gave me error.

i tried,

```
import json
f = open(".\simple.json", "r")
json_obj = json.load(f)

#json_obj.append << doesnt work
#json_obj.dump("blahblah", Ensureblahblah=False) << doesnt work too.
```

using python version 3.4.1

Comment: What is the exact error

Comment: Above written json is invalid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code guided explanation

```
import json

open_file_object = open("/home/action/workspace/playkt/data.json", 'r')
decoded_json = json.load(open_file_object)

print (decoded_json)

"""
{
  "BlockA": {
    "BlockB": {
      "name": "BlockB",
      "value": "Value_B"
    }
  }
}
"""

decoded_json["BlockA"]["BlockC"] = { "name": "BlockC", "value": "Value_C" }

print(decoded_json)

"""
{
    "BlockA": {
        "BlockB": {
            "name": "BlockB",
            "value": "Value_B"
        },
        "BlockC": {
            "name": "BlockC",
            "value": "Value_C"
        }
    }
}
"""

#write to file 
output_file = "/home/action/workspace/playkt/data.json"

with open(output_file, 'w') as write_file_object:
  #Serialize dictionary to a JSON formatted string and write to file
  write_file_object.write(json.dumps(decoded_json))
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON is just a way to serialize data. If you parse a JSON object, you'll get a python dictionary. If you parse a JSON array, you'll get a python list. If you parse a string, you get a string... etc.

So, if you parse a JS object, you'll get a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have append or dump methods.

This means:

```
import json
f = open(".\simple.json", "r")
json_obj = json.load(f)  # <--- this is a dictionary!

json_obj['BlockC'] = {'name': '...', 'value': '...'}
```

And then dump it back to the file (read the json API if you have doubts)

Comment: sorry for cant choose you,

Comment: Well, I offered an explanation and you were asking for a solution for your homework.